# How do I convert html to pdf via xelatex keep inline style

Tags: pandoc

I want convert html to pdf by pandoc, and use xelatex engien. But `<span style='font-size'>Text</span>` inline style not convert to pdf.

here is my currently in use latex-template:

```
\documentclass[$if(fontsize)$$fontsize$,$endif$$if(lang)$$babel-lang$,$endif$$if(papersize)$$papersize$,$endif$$for(classoption)$$classoption$$sep$,$endfor$]{$documentclass$}

\begin{document}
$if(title)$
\maketitle
$endif$
$if(abstract)$
\begin{abstract}
$abstract$
\end{abstract}
$endif$

$for(include-before)$
$include-before$

$endfor$
$if(toc)$
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor=$if(toccolor)$$toccolor$$else$black$endif$}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{$toc-depth$}
\tableofcontents
}
$endif$
$if(lot)$
\listoftables
$endif$
$if(lof)$
\listoffigures
$endif$
$body$

$if(natbib)$
$if(bibliography)$
$if(biblio-title)$
$if(book-class)$
\renewcommand\bibname{$biblio-title$}
$else$
\renewcommand\refname{$biblio-title$}
$endif$
$endif$
\bibliography{$for(bibliography)$$bibliography$$sep$,$endfor$}

$endif$
$endif$
$if(biblatex)$
\printbibliography$if(biblio-title)$[title=$biblio-title$]$endif$

$endif$
$for(include-after)$
$include-after$

$endfor$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would help us a lot to help you, if you would provide a minimal working example of fully compilable code illustrating your problem, starting with `\documentclass...`, the preamble with your inbound packages and the main code within `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't think Pandoc supports CSS. correct `CSS` parsing and applying to the HTML is quite  hard, the only HTML to LaTeX converter which claim to support it is [htmltopdf](http://htmltolatex.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Pandoc does support an external .css file, via the option ´-c´, have a look [here](http://pandoc.org/README.html#options-affecting-specific-writers).